# Modernizing IBM i - PF/LF -> Tables/Views/Indexes berhaviour?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Question for IBM i (OS 7.1) modernizing strategy:

Say I have some Physicals with associated logical files,

If I recreate with identical SQL Tables, Views and Indexes - will RPG, CLP programs including OPNQRYF and OVRDBF run as is? Will they require recomompile... or likely more.

I realize that logicals with field selection or compare may require some special treatment.

thanks!

Comment: Even with field selection, Charles' solution should work. Just understand that if you use a view, you will not be guaranteed to receive records in any specific order. A logical file will always provide records in a specific order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can convert a PF to a table and a LF to a view / index without needing to re-compile anything.

When converting PF to table, you can (and should) even add LONG_COLUMN_NAMES and primary key constraints without effect.

The key is to check the `Record Format Level Identifier` of you PF and the SQL table using `DSPFD`.  If they are the same, then you won't see a level check.

```
Record Format List                              
                       Record  Format Level     
 Format       Fields   Length  Identifier       
 MYDDSPFA        114      634  4BBE898C9C79B
```